# Getting selected values from select tag

Tags: php, html, laravel, css-selectors

Following is my code to select multiple values from the DB. Can I write the value that I just selected by using the following syntax of PHP?

```
<div class="form-group form-group-half">
   <span class="wt-select">
   {!! Form::select(multiple 'genders', $genders, null, array('placeholder' => trans('lang.gender'), 'v-bind:class' => '{ "is-invalid": form_step1.is_gender_error }')) !!}
   echo"$_POST['gender1']"
   <span class="help-block" v-if="form_step1.gender_error">
      <strong v-cloak>@{{form_step1.gender_error}}</strong>
   </span>
   </span>
   </div>
```

I'm trying `echo"$_POST['gender1']"` but it is just showing this text. How can I get the value from and display it just on select in php?

Comment: `echo $_POST['genders'];` the name of the select field is `genders`

Comment: If in doubt..... `print_r($_POST);` and look at what is being sent

Comment: @RiggsFolly still I'm getting string, not value

Comment: you can get data from request using **$request->get('field')**. You can also **dd($request->all())** in you controller for get all data in request.